# Enviar e-mail por VBA Excel com Azure protection

Tags: vba, excel-vba, microsoft-azure

Enviar e-mails através de macro VBA no Excel é uma tarefa simples já há algum tempo. Acredito que a maioria das empresas tem pelo menos uma planilha que dispara e-mails baseado em algum critério.

Mas com o advento da Proteção de Informações da Azure, essa mensagem aparece antes de todo envio:

[caixa de interação](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLkNX.png)

De modo que o e-mail só é enviado após o usuário interagir com a mensagem e selecionar uma classificação, o que inviabiliza o disparo de múltiplos e-mails.

Acho improvável que essa ferramenta (Azure) signifique o fim do disparo de e-mails automáticos. Portanto, alguém sabe como está sendo feito o disparo automático em empresas que adotaram o sistema de proteção da Azure?

Answer (score -2):

Utilizei a dica do "sendKeys" e deu certo para mim.
Uso o outlook 365, e acrescentei os seguintes comandos na macro:

sendKeys "%M" '(corresponde a apertar alt e entrar no submenu de mensagens)

sendKeys "Y1~" '(corresponde a selecionar o primeiro perfil de sensibilidade disponível e apertar ENTER)

[Entrar no menu de mensagens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPmM8.png)
[Selecionar a opção de sensibilidade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqpL1.png)

Fonte:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49003285/azure-classification-using-vba